# Plesk: running out of SSD space

Tags: plesk

I am running Plesk on Ubuntu in the cloud. I am running out of disk space. Migrating up to the next tier will double my price.

The cloud company has a feature where you can buy a new "volume" which is just a single directory.

Is there a way to use this volume to offload much of the content of Plesk, to free up the main drive? My backups are stored remotely.

I have been told the answer is no, that I must upgrade, but I thought I would ask some experts first. If most of Plesk's data is stored in a single directory, isn't it possible to link the two directories?

Comment: I don't know anything about Plesk, but on Linux you can control where a disk is mounted in your file tree and you can create symlinks to folders on other volumes.  Do you have root access to this machine?   Can you show the directory listing for Plesk so we can see if or how it can be broken up?

Comment: If the hosting provider has told you, "no," then it's likely they won't give you the capability to do that directly. What you might be able to do is free up space into this new volume. If you have a large archive of log file or traffic information on Plesk, you could back this up onto this other volume. If it's emails on Plesk that are taking up the space, you could migrate this to Gmail or similar.